# CSS print sheet problem

Tags: css, printing

What a maddening problem.

I'm working on a site built on top of a CMS, so the markup is... not clean. I'm trying to write a print style sheet but it's being wildly inconsistent across browsers (I know, a shock).

Link: http://www.gastongov.com/departments/county-commission/contact-info

IE7 and IE9 look fine.

IE8, the text is larger and the footer disclaimer is cut off on the right side of the page.

Firefox 4 is the worst, as the content is bumped down to the 2nd page, and any content that doesn't fit on that page is hacked off never to be seen again.

PLEASE help. I'm at the end of my rope trying to get these browsers to work in Dead Tree Mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few curly problems, but here are some easy things that will at least help diagnosing and fixing them easier, even if they don't fix the problems themselves directly.

Your print style sheet loads before 'page.css' and a bunch of other CSS files which appear to come from the CMS you're using. All of which have an effective media type of 'all'. Any styles which appear in both places can be overridden. I see you've gone crazy with `!important` in your print.css, which suggests you've maybe already thought of that, or are stuck with it.

For the text sizing issue, I would look at using a print-specific 'reset' stylesheet, to set a base font-size on the `<body>` of a sensible point size (10 or 12pt). Points make a lot of sense for print-based styles, and don't rely on the browser remapping a pixel size to points on the printer.

Then for all of your text-based elements you want to give a different size to, specify a multiplying value in ems. So, you might have:

```
body {font-size:10pt;}

h1 {font-size:1.8em;}
h2 {font-size:1.4em;}
h3 {font-size:1.2em;}
/*  etc.  */
```

As far as Firefox cutting things off goes, I seem to recall that printing is handled differently inside of forms - but I can't find where I got that information. It might be relevant, because your entire page is wrapped in a `<form>` element (thanks to your CMS, I guess). As a test, try saving out your page to static HTML, and removing that form element - see if you get a different result when you print.

Good luck - this print stuff is nasty at the best of times - worse yet when you don't control the HTML!

Comment: Here's an interesting bit of follow-up info regarding pages being cut-off in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=258397

Comment: You make all very true assumptions. The print.css is where it is and littered with !important because of the CMS. I tried your print reset suggestion on an internal copy of the site and the problem only got worse (IE8 text got huge at 12pt, other browsers it stayed the same). Stripping out the form tag didn't help Firefox, and the link you gave says the problem is fixed in Firefox 4! Is there any tool like Firebug where I can inspect my style elements as they would apply to a printed page?

Comment: This was mostly the answer, but the Firefox cut off problem stemmed from one of the CMS generated container DIVs being set as display: inline-block. FINALLY looks to be OK.